# How to generalize API handler in typescript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, abstraction

I am currently making calls to different APIs that take in different parameters and have different outputs.

### My problem

For each API, I do the following:

1. Define a class `API1Request` for the request
2. Define an interface `IAPI1Response`
3. Construct `API1Request`
4. Execute `API1Request`
5. Convert response to JSON
6. Convert JSON to `IAPI1Response` or my custom interface `IErrorResponse`
7. Check, and handle errors
8. Do something with `API1Request`

I have 5 APIs, so this process seems really repetitive and tedious.

### My Goal

I would ideally like to generalize this process so that steps 3-7 are only done once. I was wondering if there were any common pattern that I could read about to handle this problem.

### UPDATE

Here is what things are looking like in practice:

#### Request1.ts

```
class Request1 {
    id: any;
    getMetadata: () => any;

    constructor(input:string){
        this.id= {
            opportunityid: input,
            '@odata.type': 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.opportunity'
        };
        this.getMetadata = () => {
            return {
                boundParameter: null,
                parameterTypes: {
                    'id': {
                        'typeName': 'mscrm.crmbaseentity',
                        'structuralProperty': 5
                    }
                },
                operationType: 0,
                operationName: 'APIRequest1Operation'
            };
        };
    }
}

export default Request1;
```

#### IRequest1Response.ts

```
interface IRequest1Response {
    totalOrders: number;
    totalCommissions: number;
    totalBonus: number;
}

export default IRequest1Response;
```

#### index.ts

```
private getData = async () => {
    try {
        const req = new Request1(this.id);
        const response = await (this.context.webAPI as any).execute(req);
        const responseJson = response.json();

        if(responseJson.Output){
                    
            const response: IRequest1Response | IErrorResponse = JSON.parse(responseJson.Output);

            if((response as IErrorResponse).error){
                const error = response as IErrorResponse;
                const errorObj:any = {};

                if(error.status)
                    errorObj['errorCode'] = error.status;
                if(error.message)
                    errorObj['message'] = error.message;
                if(error.error_description)
                    errorObj['message'] = error.error_description;

                alert(errorObj);
            }
            else{
                const data = response as Request1Response;
                // DO SOMETHING WITH 'data'
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await this.showError(error);
    }
}
```

Every function in index.ts would look very similar, with the only difference being which request it constructs, which response it puts it into, and what we do with the data. There must be a better way to do this without repeating a lot of this code.

Comment: Is the class ceremony necessary? This is an ideal case for functional programming.

Comment: @jsejcksn I believe the classes are necessary because of the API I am bounded to... When I execute a request, it takes in a class. I have made updates to show what things are looking like in practice, and hoping that it makes my question a bit clearer

Comment: What is `this.context.webAPI`? It's hard to help without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you create one in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/Q) and update your question with a link to it?

Comment: Even without a question update, it seems like you want to make use of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/wQ5JYw) of an approach using generics and functional programming.

Comment: You want a common interface that all of your request classes implement. Something like `interface MyRequest { id: { opportunityid: string;  '@odata.type': string; }; getMetadata(): Record<string, any>; }`.  Possibly it's a generic and depends on the response type. Then you can create a `RequestHandler` class that takes my `MyRequest` as an argument to the constructor (ie. composition instead of inheritance). Possibly it takes a `MyRequest` instance, or possibly it takes the `Request1` class itself (`{ new: ( input: string ) => MyRequest }`) and instantiates individual objects in a method call.

Comment: Or possibly you have a single API class instance with a `fetchEndpointData` method that takes your `MyRequest` as an argument, rather than having a class instance for each endpoint.